# imagemapster plugin: howto programmatically make area nolonger selectable?

Tags: javascript, jquery-plugins, imagemapster

I have setup an imagemap with the jquery-plugin [imagemapster](http://www.outsharked.com/imagemapster/) 
Could you please give a tip howto let an area in the imagemape be  no longer clickable, after it has already been clicked?

I tried the following, but it does not work:

```
function userClicked (e) {
    if(e.key == okKey){
        //success
        $('img').mapster({
           areas:[ {
              key: e.key,
              isSelectable: false
           }]
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: ok, I solved it myself:  $('img').mapster('set_options',{areas:[{key:'anyAreaKey',isDeselectable:false   }]})

Answer (score 0):

$('img').mapster('set_options',{areas:[{key:'anyAreaKey',isDeselectable:false }]})